# Mysterious note found at a Pokéstop

Tags: cipher

In a rare moment where I wasn't staring at my phone while playing Pokémon GO, I was at a Pokéstop and saw a bit of paper on the ground. It was obviously ripped from a notebook while in a hurry while a trainer was running around playing the game.

This is what was written on the page:

`cTicwe evoaestme ent ne o   yboevh i toe coy a  Ica,rtiroh  Iaesst.mk eroerste rbet r wmO    tb ehkhm isa i Vnutyehoeeaeb tahr .atlu dt  st  nttln!,ve`

Can anyone help me find the key and the message?

Hint:

> On the back of the note you can just make out written the following:
> `M: 32, T: 32, W: 32, T: 30, F: 24 D Train` 
> You feel sure that this relates in the cipher in some way.

Comment: Frequency Analysis
e : 19     t : 16     o : 9     a : 8     i : 7     r : 7
s : 6       h : 6      n : 5     v : 4     m : 4   b : 4
c : 4       y : 3      u : 2     w : 2    k : 2     l : 2
d : 1     

oe => 4
st => 4

Comment: That's probably not going to help. I will say that the spaces are important and should be preserved.

Comment: Wild guess on my side was something with the pokedex.. couldnt get anything that looked plausible to me to work tho

Comment: I'm getting bits and pieces with brute force but its pretty muddled. Nothing close enough to solve it yet.

Comment: It is connected to the numbers in the Pokédex, but rearranged in a certain famous order.

Comment: The only famous order I recall (related to Nintendo) is the [Konami Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) ... not sure if that is the "order" we are looking for..

Comment: It's not related to Nintendo, it's directly Pokémon related. The hint should help you.

Comment: I see TIIOV in capitals,maybe anagram, is there any reference to any Pokemon directly ?

Comment: Oh, I think I know how to solve this one!  It's the Pokérap!

Comment: @Will: Did you try permuting the other way?

Comment: Brilliant! It has to be Pokérap :D (I know these comments will be deleted O:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per Deusovi's comment(s) and the rest of the answers here, the length of the text (150 characters) and the hint both lead us to

> [The Kanto Pokérap](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kanto_Pok%C3%A9rap)
>
>  In order, the [dex numbers](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_Kanto_Pok%C3%A9dex_number) of the Pokémon listed in the rap are: `101, 50, 32, 56, 3, 19, 22, 16, 119, 135, 149, 92, 77, 134, 62, 12, 49, 60, 33, 55, 2, 88, 71, 146, 34, 83, 63, 39, 99, 111, 36, 40, 41, 57, 52, 95, 74, 78, 82, 143, 94, 114, 118, 21, 110, 86, 130, 80, 140, 53, 46, 116, 20, 81, 64, 70, 132, 91, 10, 27, 1, 4, 76, 25, 65, 84, 48, 67, 115, 97, 125, 136, 9, 61, 43, 96, 26, 31, 69, 121, 11, 105, 14, 35, 85, 117, 45, 98, 108, 128, 13, 29, 66, 90, 137, 107, 144, 124, 30, 15, 93, 7, 113, 47, 102, 89, 87, 17, 131, 37, 112, 6, 68, 127, 109, 51, 42, 120, 129, 38, 23, 139, 123, 72, 148, 126, 28, 106, 54, 59, 133, 103, 141, 145, 147, 58, 122, 104, 75, 100, 44, 5, 8, 150, 73, 142, 138, 79, 18, 24`
>
>  Permuting the characters in the note in that order: the `c` goes 101st, the `T` 50th, the `i` 32nd, and so on

we get the message

> `I want to be the very best   keino one ever was. To catch teem is my real test, to train them is my cause. Oh buick, over there a Voltorb! I need that`

which looks like it's supposed to mean this, with a few errors:

> I want to be the very best [li]ke[ ]no one ever was. To catch t[h]em is my real test, to train them is my cause. Oh [q]uick, over there a Voltorb! I need that

Comment: Put the number for male Nidoran before female Nidoran, and it might make a bit more sense. But well done for solving it!

Comment: @James I did. Nidoran♂ is #032, while Nidoran♀ is #029. I see now that swapping them (putting _female first_) moves the misplaced `i` to the correct spot; but there's still a space in place of an `l`, an `e` in place of an `h`, and a `b` in place of `q`. These mistakes in the plaintext are consistent with character counts of the ciphertext (e.g., the notable absence of a `q`).

Comment: That said, I enjoyed this puzzle regardless of the minor errors. :)

Comment: Ahh I should've checked it more thoroughly before deleting the script that generated the string. Well deduced!

Answer (score 6):

Googling "Pokemon D Train" gets us..

> this [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvsifyZvgGE) by James "D Train" Williams and Babi Floyd. 
> The lyrics are found [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kanto_Pok%C3%A9rap). Under the TV Edit lyrics, you can see the Pokemon categorised by days of the week. The numbers for each day correspond to the numbers given in the hint.

The cipher is...

> rearranging the characters according to the Pokedex order in the lyrics.

The message is...

> to be honest, I messed up halfway and might take a while to redo so others are welcome to answer.
>  
> The first 107 characters of the deciphered message are the first 4 lines of the Pokemon theme (I want to be the very best.. to train them is my cause.) The remaining seems to be an actual message (I can just about make out 'Voltorb').

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about the pokeybeasts but this might help someone:

> The initials in the hint appear to represent the days of the week. **M**onday, **T**uesday, **W**ednesday, **T**hursday, **F**riday.

Answer (score 0):

> 32 + 32 + 32 + 30 + 24 = 150, or the exact number of Pokemons available for catching in Pokémon Go. So Pokémons seems to be categorized under week days.